# setFragmentResult and setFragmentResultListener packages not found (Unresolved reference)

Tags: android, android-fragments, androidx

Could anyone help me please how can I import [setFragmentResult and setFragmentResultListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/fragment/app/package-summary#setfragmentresult) into my project?

I have implemented 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.2.5' but it seems it is not the right package.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

First, make sure you have `"androidx.fragment:fragment:1.3.0-alpha08"` as a dependency. These methods were added in `1.3.0-alpha04`, so make sure you have at least that version.

Then, these are the imports:

```kotlin
import androidx.fragment.app.setFragmentResult
```

and

```kotlin
import androidx.fragment.app.setFragmentResultListener
```

Comment: Nice, btw the last version "1.3.0-rc01" at doc page (it is still a candidate release state): https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/fragment

Answer (score 13):

If you are using java please try this code below :

setFragmentResult :

```
requireActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().setFragmentResult("request_Key", new Bundle());
```

setFragmentResultListener :

```
requireActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().setFragmentResultListener("request Key", getViewLifecycleOwner(), new FragmentResultListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFragmentResult(@NonNull String requestKey, @NonNull Bundle result) {

            }
        });
```

dependency use :

```
implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment:1.3.0"
```

Comment: The above was helpful but I found I needed to use getParentFragmentManager() instead of requireActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()

Comment: @Martin : I saw  getParentFragmentManager() too but getSupportFragmentManager() was working for me. ^^

Comment: This is supposed to be the equivalent of startActivityForResult, right? If so, what about initiating it? And shouldn't having this "request_Key" need to be unique between all Fragments that the Activity ever has to deal with?

Answer (score 8):

As of Feb'21, 1.3.0 is now available. [Source](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/androidx.fragment/fragment-ktx)

```
implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.3.0'
debugImplementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-testing:1.3.0'
```

This should resolve the reference.

Comment: Recent package name is 
implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.6.0-alpha02"